# Using Viewmodel and datepicker with Dotnet Highchart in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, highcharts

I am using Dotnet Highchart that is based on C# code that has output code javascript.
[Dotnet HighChart](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/)

This is almost how my chart looks like:

[image: Charts]

I am using data from my database to give this chart data by using LINQ queries.

I have a column "Completed Date" in my entity and I need to make two textboxes with datepicker so user can choose Start and end dates of Completed Date.Then the user should be able to click on a submit button and then the chart should update and show the statistic between the two dates. I have the complete LINQ Query for this

This is the LINQ query that I am going to use:

```
public List<CoreValueAndAverageGrade> GetAverageGradeForAllCoreValues(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {



            return db.CoreValue
                .Where(coreValue => coreValue.CoreValueQuestion
                    .Any(coreValueQuestion => coreValueQuestion.SubjectType.Ignored_Statistic == false))
                .Select(coreValue => new CoreValueAndAverageGrade
                {
                    CoreValue = coreValue,
                    AverageGrade = coreValue.CoreValueQuestion
                        .Where(coreValueQuestion => coreValueQuestion.SubjectType.Ignored_Statistic == false)
                        .Average(coreValueQuestion => coreValueQuestion.SelectedQuestions
                            .Where(selectedQuestion => selectedQuestion.GoalCardQuestionAnswer != null
                                && selectedQuestion.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade.HasValue

                            && selectedQuestion.GoalCard.Completed_Date >= startDate
                            && selectedQuestion.GoalCard.Completed_Date <= endDate
                                )
                            .Average(selectedQuestion => selectedQuestion.GoalCardQuestionAnswer.Grade.Value))
                })
                .ToList();
        }
```

This is my ViewModel

```
 public class OfficeStatisticNKIViewModel
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

In my GET action method I have following code:

```
public ActionResult OfficeStatistic()
{
    {
       OfficeStatisticNKIViewModel model = new OfficeStatisticNKIViewModel();
       model.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
       model.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        var averageGrades = OfficeStatisticRepository.GetAverageGradeForAllCoreValues(model.StartDate, model.EndDate);

        var dataItems = (averageGrades.Select(averageGrade => averageGrade.AverageGrade).ToArray());
        Data data = new Data(
            dataItems.Select(y => new Point {Color = GetBarColour(y), Y = y}).ToArray());


        Highcharts chart1 = new Highcharts("Chart")
         .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = averageGrades.Select(averageGrade => averageGrade.CoreValue.Name).ToArray() })
         .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Min = 0, Max = 10, TickInterval = 1, Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Betygskalan" } })
         .SetSeries(new Series {  Data = data, Name = "Snittbetyg" })
         .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
         .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Örebro Statistik", })
         .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column });


        return View(new Container(new[] { chart1 }));

    }
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to do the post action method, The chart needs to update with the new the statistic, do I need some kind of ajax or can I do this on the serverside?

Any kind of help or tips is very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to update the chart asynchronously (with Javascript), or do you just want to postback and have the entire page rendered again?

Comment: I did something like this for a project and simply used a partial view. Used datepickers and sent the data back to the controller. The controller ran the query using those results and then re-rendered the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/350721/